# POSIX regex: match only within comma-delimited items

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Context: I'm writing a shell script to help manage a simple database stored in a human-readable way in text files and edited using a normal text editor. (Each entry is a text file whose name is an ID number, and all files are stored in a single directory.)

My current problem is searching. There are some *headers* which are basically data fields at the top of the file. For instance, let's take the tags field, which begins on a new line with `Tags:\t` (where `\t` is a literal tab character) and then has a list of comma-separated tags. I'd like to be able to plug a regex provided by the user into a larger call to `grep` and have the user's regex match *only within each comma-separated item*.

Here's a bit from my documentation that describes what I would like to happen:

---

**hregexes** are EREs matched only within comma-separated items. For instance, with the header `Tags:    foo, bar baz`:

```
REGEX     :: MATCHES?
foo       :: yes
bar       :: yes
baz       :: yes
az        :: yes
.*baz     :: yes
ba.*az    :: yes
o, ba     :: no
foo.*baz  :: no
```

---

This would ideally work purely with POSIX extended regexps, for consistency with the rest of the system; I had a simplified version of the search working in Python but decided I should rewrite that portion so the system wouldn't have some searches take POSIX regexps and some Python ones.

I did try to come up with a pattern, but I'm not really good enough with regexps to do something this complicated. In the following attempt, `$2` is the header we're looking for, and `$3` is the pattern to match in that header.

```
grep -El "$2:   (|.*,|.*, )[^,]*$3[^,]*(,|\b)" *.dre
```

This doesn't miss any results it should catch, but it has the problem that `o, ba` and `foo.*baz` both match when they shouldn't; at this point I might as well just search for `$2:   .*$3`.

If this isn't possible with a single ERE, is there another good way to do this in Bash? My database already has over a thousand files and could easily grow to many times that, so I'd prefer not to be looping over each file and then over each item in the comma-separated list and incurring shell overhead every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution, based on Perry's idea of changing the separator, is not foolproof, but preserves the desirable running time while making it pretty hard to screw up.

First, we choose a delimiter to replace the commas with; I have chosen `@@@@@`, reasoning that this will not occur in any properly formed tag. (The tags are normally purely alphanumeric.)

We then modify the user's regexp to replace `.` with `[^@]` so that no expression will cross the `@@@@@` boundaries unless explicitly composed to. I may be missing some other matches, say `[[:punct:]]`; I'm not terribly worried about those, but if someone has thoughts about other special characters that might be problematic, I'd like to hear about them.

Finally, we create a stream that contains all of the `Tags` lines, edit it to contain just the filenames and the new `@`-delimited tags, apply the user's pattern match to this stream, and then remove everything but the filenames from the stream of matches.

Final code:

```
header="$2"
pattern=$(echo "$3" | sed -e 's/\./[^@]/')
grep -m 1 "$header: " *.dre | sed -e "s/$header:        //" | \
    sed -e 's/, /@@@@@/g' | grep -E "$pattern" | \
    sed -e 's/\([0-9]\{5\}\.dre\):.*/\1/'
```

(`[0-9]\{5\}\.dre` is an expression that matches all legal filenames.)

Example output:

```
00775.dre
00787.dre
00788.dre
00883.dre
00889.dre
```

(Obviously, the matches can be saved into a variable for further processing; that's what I'm doing here.)

Comment: I didn't try it but it looks like you're on the right track.  You're also bumping up against the limits of what you're going to be able to achieve in pure shell so bear in mind that the next feature request from your users may push you over the edge into writing some helpers in a lower level language :)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to change the commas to something that works better as a separator in grep, i.e. a newline.

```
head -1 $DATA_FILE | sed -E 's/,/\'$'\n/g' | grep -qE "$SEARCH"

if [ $? == 0 ]
then
    echo "Pattern found: $DATA_FILE"
else
    echo "Pattern not found: $DATA_FILE"
fi
```

`$DATA_FILE` is the file containing the tags.
`$SEARCH` is the regular expression being sought.

The `if` statement would obviously be replaced with logic appropriate to your application.

The `head` command extracts the first line (the "Tag:" line) from the file.
The `sed` command replaces any commas on that line with newlines (it might be wise to remove the "Tag:" at this point as well to avoid false positives).
The `grep` then just has to search each resulting set of lines for the input regex and return a status indicating whether it was found.

The minimum amount of each data file is searched.

Comment: This works (except `Tags` isn't necessarily the first line, so I instead use `grep -hm 1 'Tags:'`), but it requires looping over every file in the directory in Bash, which has slowed down the search by a factor of 60, going from nearly instantaneous from the user's perspective to several seconds.

Comment: I think I've found a workable solution, which I've posted as an answer; I'd be interested to hear your thoughts on that.